# Convertir código Visual Fox a C#

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Hay alguna forma de convertir código en **VFP** a código C#. Alguna **applicacion** o en la **web**.

¿Tienen alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Comment: Tengo entendido que no se puede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible hacerlo con un convertidor o aplicacion.

En este articulo (en ingles) dan una aproximacion de los pasos a seguir para hacer la conversion:

[From VFP to .NET](http://www.codemag.com/article/0703042)